# How to run Clojure in Kotlin?

Tags: clojure, kotlin, clojure-java-interop, kotlin-interop

Is it possible to run clojure in kotlin? More specific in spring?

I have made scrapers in clojure and I want to use them on a web application written in kotlin. How does that look like in kotlin? The code..

Comment: If you know how to run Clojure from Java, then you already know how to run it from Kotlin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using the `clojure.java.api.Clojure` class, as documented in the [Java interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop) section of Clojure reference documentation under the heading [Calling Clojure From Java](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_calling_clojure_from_java).

A Java example:

```
import clojure.java.api.Clojure;
import clojure.lang.IFn;

// this part taken from the reference page linked above:
IFn plus = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "+");
plus.invoke(1, 2);
```